# Is "inspired by X in their work" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

> These philosophers were inspired by Hegel **in** their philosophical work.
>   Like Karl Marx, these philosophers took a few ideas from Hegel and put
>   it into their own systems.

Is "inspired by X in their work" grammatically correct?

I am not sure if "in" is appropriate, but can't think of a more succinct way to say this.

Comment: What do you think might be wrong with it?

Comment: using "in" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @repomonster - Googling ["inspired in their work"](https://www.google.com/search?q="inspired+in+their+work") yields an awful lot of hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's technically grammatically correct, but I would more frequently hear something like

> These philosophers' ideas were inspired by Hegel.

or

> Hegel inspired these philosophers' work.

I think the major difference is people tend to prefer to not repeat themselves more than necessary, rather than grammar concerns. Of course, some really prefer the lack of passive voice in the second option I offered.